# I am finding difficulty saving the data separately in one collection

Tags: angular, mongodb

I have 3 different pages and the content is loading from one collection.  the content contains an ID, version & path. the path is an array of objects one of the property  "service" will separate the content of the page for example if the "service": "page1" this object will be pushed to an Array and this will load the page1 data and so on. ID and version remain same.

Here is the code

```
"_id" : "admin",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "path" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "ABC",
            "number" : "1234",
            "position" : "ABC",
            "service" : "page1"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "ABC",
            "number" : "2233",
            "position" : "ABC",
            "service" : "page3"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "ABC",
            "number" : "12345",
            "position" : "ABC",
            "service" : "page2"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "ABC",
            "number" : "2345",
            "position" : "ABC",
            "service" : "page3",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to load the data but the issue I am facing while saving the date, if I select save in page1 the content of page2 and page3 will be removed only page1 data will be available and if I select save in page2 the content of page 1 and page3 will be removed. I need to save the data according to the value of the "service"
    //save the data

```
this.http.patch(URL + 'document/' + c, { "$set": { path: temp.path } }, this.hdr).toPromise().then(res => {...})
```

I am working on angular 6 and the database is MongoDB Please help me with this saving issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you retrieve the elements of path which match a query for one of your pages, which are placed in an array. (which I assume from your poorly documented question is "temp.path").

You then proceed to update path to be this array, which now no longer contains the objects for the other pages.

Solution:
You need to {$set: {'path': fullPath}}
assuming

```
// the entire path array as present in your collection
    fullPath =[{service: "page1", ... }, {service: "page1", ...}, {service: "page2"}...] 
    temp.path = fullPath.filter(p=>p.service==="page1");
```

This should work because the variables are passed by reference and the array temp.path refers to the objects of fullPath. Which means modifications you've made to temp.path will be reflected in fullPath

Edit: This seems lightweight enough that you can get your entire path to the client, and push pull the entire path on changes.
 If not it gets more complicated, and you need a separate update operation for each changed member and to use the $expr operator to match the array element of path you're trying to modify.